# Is there a way to pull the RSSI value of a bluetooth connection in real-time?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am attempting to create a C# program that will pull RSSI signal strength values from a bluetooth device. I am a novice when it comes to using C#, but I figured it would be the easiest way to create this program. Basically the idea is to pull the signal strength as a double or possibly an integer and then use that value in an if else statement. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and creating a console app. After doing a bit of research I found UwpDesktop in the NuGet Packages, but I'm hitting a bump where I don't know where else to continue. I have the Bluetooth devices MAC address and the device uses bluetooth LE. Hopefully someone can help, thank you.

Comment: Rading RSSI value is different for LE and Classic. So which one do you want to use? Is your device LE or Classic?

Comment: @MikePetrichenko It is LE, apologies for not specifying.

Comment: On Window splatform you can read RSSI from BLE devices only when the devices are advertising. To do that you have to use the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher?view=winrt-22000). Once device conencted it usually stops advertising so you can't get the RSSI value. (Even you use some system property reading after device connected you will get last advertised RSSI value).